# Comparing column definitions between Oracle databases

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have two different databases Miadb and DWH. I want to compare the column definitions of two tables in different database.

I wrote this SQL but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='ibrmt030@miadb' 
minus
SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='ibrmt030@dwh';
```

Error-Message is :

```
ORA-00997: geçersiz LONG veri türü kullanımı
    00997. 00000 -  "illegal use of LONG datatype"

Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 8
```

Answer (score 2):

USER_TAB_COLUMNS does not contain entries for tables in other databases.

Possibly this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS@miadb WHERE TABLE_NAME='IBRMT030' 
minus
SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS@dwh WHERE TABLE_NAME='IBRMT030';
```

There are many metadata columns in there that could cause the rows to not match between systems (and one of them may be of the LONG datatype, which is causing that error). Limit your query to just the essential columns.

Incidentally, if the database at DWH has extra columns then this will not be identified in this query. You'd do better to implement a full outer join between the data sets.

Comment: Also `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` [includes the `DATA_DEFAULT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm) column, which is of type `LONG`. The [restrictions on LONG columns](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#sthref108) include '`LONG` and `LONG RAW` columns cannot be used in distributed SQL statements and cannot be replicated', so that column would have to be excluded from the comparison, even if `MINUS` wasn't already complaining about it.

Comment: Oracle should have added a non-LONG column with that same information in it if they were worried about historical compatibility.